# How to fix Pipeline-Script "Expected a step" error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run a simple pipeline-script in Jenkins with 2 stages.
The script itself creates a textFile and checks if this one exists.
But when i try to run the job I get an **"Expected a step"** error.

I have read somewhere that you cant have an `if` inside a step so that might be the problem but if so how can I check without using the `if`?

```
pipeline {
    agent {label 'Test'}
    stages {
        stage('Write') {
            steps {
                writeFile file: 'NewFile.txt', text: 
                '''Sample HEADLINE'''
                println "New File created..."
            }
        }
        stage('Check') {
            steps {        
                Boolean bool = fileExists 'NewFile.txt'
                if(bool) {
                    println "The File exists :)"
                }
                else {
                    println "The File does not exist :("
                }            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the script to create a "NewFile.txt" in the agents workspace and print a text to the console confirming that it exists.

But I actually get two **"Expected a step"** errors.
At the Line starting with `Boolean bool = ...`
and at `if(bool) ...`

Comment: Did you have look at https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You are missing a `script{}` -step which is required in a declarative pipeline.

[Quote](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script):

> The script step takes a block of Scripted Pipeline and executes that
> in the Declarative Pipeline.

```
stage('Check') {
    steps {        
        script {
            Boolean bool = fileExists 'NewFile.txt'
            if (bool) {
                println "The File exists :)"
            } else {
                println "The File does not exist :("
            }   
        }         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple reasons why you may get the `"Expected a step"` error.

Mine occurred because I used single quotes `'` to surround a step script instead of double quotes `"`.  For example:

```groovy
stage("Build") {
    steps {
        sh "./build.sh ${SECRET_KEY}"
    }
}
```

The string used above uses string interpolation (or I guess it's called a "templateable string"?), which won't work for a single-quoted string.

Thought I'd add this answer here in case someone comes from Google and the accepted answer doesn't work!