# Step expected in Jenkins Groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am having below groovy script for my Jenkins pipeline. But when running its giving error as step expected where my script already having step. Can anyone suggest what's wrong here..

Script file

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Workspace Preparation') {
        steps {
            sh """
                rm -rf ${workspace}/*
            """
        }
    }
   stage('Get Deployment files') {
       steps {
            dir("${workspace}/deployfiles") {
                if("${params.componentType}"=="A") {
                    echo "A component deployment"
                    checkout(## necessary step)
                }
                else if ("${params.componentType}"=="B") {
                    echo "B component deployment"
                    checkout(## necessary step)
                }
                else  {
                    echo "Invalid"
                }


              }
       }
    }
}
```

}

Getting error as

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 19: Expected a step @ line 14, column 6.
                    if("${params.componentType}"=="A") {
        ^
enter code here
enter code here
```

Comment: I believe, inside `dir` could be only steps without `if` or other scripting.

Comment: `dir(•••){ checkout(•••) }`

Comment: after updating code as below 'stage('Get Deployment files') {   
   if("${params.componentType}"=="A") {
    steps {
     dir("${workspace}/deployfiles") {
                        echo "A component deployment"
     }
                }
   }
   else if ("${params.componentType}"=="B") {
    steps {
     dir("${workspace}/deployfiles") {
                        echo "B component deployment"
     }
    }
   }
   else  {
                echo "Invalid"
            } 
        }'   getting error as "Not a valid stage section definition:"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `script-block`. 
([Source](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script))

Such a block gives you acces to execute groovy code (for, if-else etc. etc.)

```
stage('Check') {
        steps {        
            script { // Allows to execute groovy code
               dir (...) {
                 if (...)
               }    
            }         
        }
```

See also: [How to fix Pipeline-Script “Expected a step” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508871/how-to-fix-pipeline-script-expected-a-step-error/55510151#55510151)

Comment: Yes you are correct. After making code like  `stage('Get Deployment files') {
  steps {
   script{
    if("${params.componentType}"=="A") {
    dir("${workspace}/deployfiles") {
     sh """
                        echo "A component deployment"
     """
     }
    }
    else if ("${params.componentType}"=="B") {
    dir("${workspace}/deployfiles") {
     sh """
                        echo "B component deployment"
      """
     }
    }
    else  {
     sh """
     echo "Invalid"
     """
    } 
   }`....