# How to correctly call a function in the declarative Jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Good day!

I would like to call a function that sets a a choice parameter with the list of folder in the branch. I getting null value at the end.

My Jenkins file looks like the below:

```
void findCollectionDirs() {
    directories = sh (
        script: "find . -path './[^.]*/*/*' -prune -type d",
        returnStdout: true
    )
    return directories
}
def directories

pipeline () {
    agent {
        label 'slave'
    }
    triggers {
        cron(cron_string)
    }
    parameters {
           choice(choices: "\n" + directories, description: 'Please select a directory', name: 'directory')
     }

    stages {
        stage ("Checkout scm") {
              steps {
                  deleteDir()
                  checkout scm
                  //sh 'directories = findCollectionDirs()'
                  findCollectionDirs()
            }
        }
```

I tried by calling it as below:

`sh 'directories = findCollectionDirs()'`
or,
`findCollectionDirs()`
or 
`directories.findCollectionDirs()`

but the value still `null`.

Can someone help me to call correctly the function so I get the right values in the choice parameter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the pipeline compile or is there any syntax error appearing?

Comment: when using `findCollectionDirs()`it compiles
when using the other 2 it throws an error

Comment: Can you provide the error message, please?

Comment: for `sh 'directories = findCollectionDirs()'`I got ` Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

and for the last try, I got : `WorkflowScript: 30: Method calls on objects not allowed outside "script" blocks. @ line 30, column 19.
                     directories.findCollectionDirs()`

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508871/how-to-fix-pipeline-script-expected-a-step-error