# How to parse JSON file in Jenkinsfile and read the key value pair

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm fairly new to Jenkins, Jenkinsfile and Groovy and not sure how to read a JSON file in Jenkinsfile. I read the article at: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace. However, the article is not clear with its implementation. I tried following code, but it fails.

```
def jFile = readJSON file: 'file.json'
pipeline 
{
    //agent any
    agent 
    {
        // Some code
    }
    stages 
    {
        stage('Init') 
        { 
            steps 
            {
                echo jFile['context']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the file within a Step in the declarative Pipeline.

```
pipeline 
{
    //agent any
    agent 
    {
        // Some code
    }
    stages 
    {
        stage('Init') 
        { 
            steps 
            {
              script {
                def jFile = readJSON file: 'file.json'
                echo "${jFile['context']}"
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, however that didn't work. Got an error: `Expected a step @ line 51, column 17. def jFile = readJSON file: 'file.json'`

Comment: From an another SO post I found that `def jFile = readJSON file: 'file.json'` that should be part of `environment {}` it does removes the error but to through another, i.e. `Cannot get property 'context' on null object`. However, the `context` does exist in the JSON file

Comment: You need to wrap the code into a script{}-block, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508871/how-to-fix-pipeline-script-expected-a-step-error/55510151#55510151. Furhtermore `jFile.context` should also work to access the value.